# Using StreamReader to get lines

Tags: c#-4.0, stream

I would like to read a text file line by line ;i am using `StreamReader`

```
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(@"d:\testfile.txt");
```

how to read the file line by line?

Answer (score 1):

```
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(@"d:\testfile.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `StreamReader.ReadLine` method seems like the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(@"d:\testfile.txt");
 while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
 {
        string line= rdr.ReadLine();
       // do your stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   while (!rdr.EndOfStream) { string line = rdr.ReadLine(); }
```